# Fluid Dynamic Engine/Simple Wave API Java or Objective C

Tags: java, objective-c, fluid, physics-engine

I am looking for the fluid and of course the basics of the fluid itself and then have all the objects interact with each other.a simple wave engine, IE physics engine that handles a surface wave upon a fluid, and can handle refactions and reflections off objects.

I really don't want to start from scratch, and most of the fluid dynamic engines seem a bit overkill for what I need.

I just need to basically be able to describe a wave, and objects in and on the surface of

I know there must be something out there that can do this without reinventing the wheel.

Basically I intend to have a grid and each grid element can have an object in it, the object may effect the wave, or not, it may reflect/deflect the wave, it may decrease the wave as it passes or it could even increase the wave as it passes.  It should handle summing multiple waves if they exist in the same part of the grid at the same time, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A full fluid dynamic simulation of surface waves is not a trivial problem.

I haven't looked at the code, but this might get you started:

[2-D Ripple Tank Simulation Applet](http://www.falstad.com/ripple/)